# Solving groovy module version conflict

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

How to solve groovy module (groovy-xml) version conflict?

The version 2.4.12 is what my currently project depends on, however, groovysh somehow preload a higher version:

```
$ groovysh
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
    at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Main.main(Main.groovy:74)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-xml is loaded in version 3.0.7 and you are trying to load version 2.4.12
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:510)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModulesFrom(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:37)
    ... 12 more
```

More info, this is Mac, and groovy is installed by `brew install groovy`, and there is no GROOVY related environment variables created:

```
$ env | grep GROOVY | wc
      0       0       0
```

Comment: how is the dependency configured on your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use skdman to manage your Groovy installations, this will create the GROVY_HOME env variable for you, the other way is to find the location of your groovy installation and create a GROVY_HOME env pointing to `bin` location inside Groovy folder.

Comment: I don't know if this is the easiest way, but I found this is the only way I can make it working. Thanks Joxebus.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the fact that when you install groovy, the installer creates an environment variable called "GROOVY_HOME". To resolve your conflict you should remove the 3.0.7 as the default version in your environment.

**EDIT ( see OP comment )**

In case the above solution doesn't work for you, here is another way:

Edit the project's `build.gradle` to force gradle load your suitable version of groovy :

```
configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { force 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all: 2.4.12' } }
```

Comment: Thx, please check out my updated question -- there is no GROOVY related environment variables created. What should I do in such situation?

Comment: What do you get when you type "groovy -version" in your console ? v3 or v2 ?
If you have v3 on your system, you must force gradle to load your projet with v2; like this :

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all: 2.4.12'
    }
}

Comment: Yes, "groovy -version" shows "Groovy Version: 3.0.7", and so does groovysh. I'm running groovysh outside my project, so how to enforce groovysh to load/start with v2 then? I'm quite new to all these, and still don't know where to put the "resolutionStrategy" yet, but my project builds OK under IDEA.

Comment: Thx  kylexy, Just that my project is OK. It builds OK without any problem. It is the groovysh that I'm running ***outside*** of my project that is causing me the problem in OP. how to enforce groovysh to load/start with v2? If I am to set GROOVY_HOME  environment variable myself, how can I know what to set, i.e., where the groovy v2 is? BTW, I think I only have Groovy Version: 3.0.7 though, have only installed this one. I didn't install any v2 groovy packages. thx